# KAFKA - ERROR Disk error while locking directory

Tags: apache-kafka

I got this error `ERROR Disk error while locking directory` while trying to start `kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

```
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,323] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,323] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,324] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,340] ERROR Disk error while locking directory /opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data/.lock
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at kafka.utils.FileLock.<init>(FileLock.scala:31)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$lockLogDirs$1(LogManager.scala:235)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:118)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.flatMap$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.flatMap(ArraySeq.scala:38)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.lockLogDirs(LogManager.scala:233)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:104)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1084)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:253)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,344] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data/recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
    at kafka.server.checkpoints.CheckpointFile.<init>(CheckpointFile.scala:45)
    at kafka.server.checkpoints.OffsetCheckpointFile.<init>(OffsetCheckpointFile.scala:57)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$recoveryPointCheckpoints$1(LogManager.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq.map(ArraySeq.scala:38)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.<init>(LogManager.scala:105)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$.apply(LogManager.scala:1084)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:253)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:82)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration in `server.properties`?

Comment: Well. It is default. I did not change anything except `log.dirs` directory

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to see. The configuration of `log.dirs`.

Comment: `# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files`
`log.dirs=/opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data`

Comment: Is this the first time you are firing Kafka server up?

Comment: Exactly. This is the first time I started Kafka server

Comment: Okay then. My answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, the user that starts the Kafka Server process does not have access to your `log.dirs`:

```
[2020-05-21 23:44:11,344] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data/recovery-point-offset-checkpoint
```

---

You can either:

- Change `log.dirs` (Make sure NOT to use `/tmp/`)
- Or grant read/write access for `/opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data/`

---

If none of the above options works for you, then probably it might be worth checking if the directory actually exists. If not, simply create it by running

```
mkdir -p /opt/kafka2.13/kafka_2.13-2.5.0/data_log_tu_tao/kafka_data
```

---

As a side note, I wouldn't say that `/opt/` is the best place to store data.

Answer (score 4):

This is known issue with Kafka distribution for windows. Refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13391

Either use Kafka 2.8 (kafka_2.12-2.8.1.tgz) or wait for Kafka 3.0.1 or Kafka 3.1.0

Answer (score 3):

For people using Kafka on windows and having a related error to

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:

This is a common error when log retention happens.
Kafka doesn’t have good support for windows filesystem.
You can use WSL2 or Docker to work around these limitations
Try to use  kafka_2.12-2.8.1.tgz. This resolved the issue for me.